# Binding for injecting HttpControllerContext for Web Api using ninject

Tags: ninject, asp.net-web-api

I have a service that takes `HttpControllerContext` for constructor injection. What is the binding for this? The bindings are setup in the NinjectWebCommon file under WebActivator.

By binding, I mean like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
kernel.Bind<HttpControllerContext>().To</* ??? */ >(); //Whats the binding?
```

Comment: this might help: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/04/19/WiringHttpControllerContextWithCastleWindsor.aspx

Comment: @tugberk I've read that and his previous posts a few times but I can't seem to understand it at the level of how to do it in ninject and his site is the only thing that came up in searches.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? There is a newer post [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/10/03/DependencyInjectioninASP.NETWebAPIwithCastleWindsor/) and you will just need to implement a class: `public class ContextCapturingControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator` and bind it as `kernel.Bind<IHttpControllerActivator>().To<ContextCapturingControllerActivator>();`